# google marker based on users marker

Tags: wordpress, maps, google-maps-markers, marker, vs-web-site-project

i'm trying to build a website with ability for user to submit a post and with that post i want the users to add the location by marker on map or by search address and in the post form page
and i want to add another map with marker of the users in the posts page
for example this [airbnb website](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Los-Angeles--CA--United-States/experiences?tab_id=experience_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fexperiences&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=unknown&ne_lat=33.135813286387325&ne_lng=-116.25923981101619&sw_lat=31.50185975725632&sw_lng=-117.75067676932917&zoom=9&search_by_map=true&query=%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B3%20%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B3%2C%20%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A7&checkin=2020-06-29&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1588186856_ZWZjYmM0ZjhkMGRh&display_currency=USD)

do you think this is possible?
i already built my website and used wordpress and multiple plugins but for post i used wpforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggestion in not entirely specific to WordPress. However, if this is applicable to your implementation, you can add markers on a map using the [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

So in your form, you can include a [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#video) to search for an address in your form page. Then get the place's details using the **getPlace()** function including the coordinates of the selected address to plot onto your map which looks something like this:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
var marker;

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);
      });
```

Here's acomplete example you can follow: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

You can checkout this link for more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete